# How to create a radar chart in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have been trying to create an interactive radar or spider chart in R shiny.
Based on my code below, I have encountered an error: "object df1 not found".
Not sure how to create radar chart anyway.

I em expecting to manipulate the spider chart using years, with measures as vertices in radar graph.

My dataframe looks like below, do I need to transpose ?

```
STATE   YEAR    measure    value

CA      2017    all_am     5000
NY      2017    all_am     6000  
FL      2017    all_am     7000
CA      2017    all_hw     5000
NY      2017    all_hw     6000  
FL      2017    all_hw     7000

CA      2016    all_am     5000
NY      2016    all_am     6000  
FL      2016    all_am     7000
CA      2016    all_hw     5000
NY      2016    all_hw     6000  
FL      2016    all_hw     7000

CA      2015    all_am     5000
NY      2015    all_am     6000  
FL      2015    all_am     7000
CA      2015    all_hw     5000
NY      2015    all_hw     6000  
FL      2015    all_hw     7000
```

Server.r

```
install.packages("shinydashboard")

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(graphics)
require(radarchart)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df <- read.csv("C:/Users/Shruti/Desktop/Try2/newT1.csv")
  head(df)  

  df1 <- df[, (names(df) %in% c("STATE", "YEAR", "measure", "value"))]
  head(df1)


  df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0


  yearinput <- reactive({
    df1%>%
      filter(value == input$years)})   

  output$radarPlot <- renderchartJSRadar({


races <- df1[which(yearinput()$measure)]

chartJSRadar(races, distinct(raceinput()$measure))           

  })
})
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(fmsb)
library(graphics)
require(radarchart)

shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Working on it"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(

       box(
         title = "VALUES",
         sliderInput(
          "years",
          "Select Year:",
          min = min(df1$YEAR),
          max = max(df1$YEAR),
          value = c(min(df1$YEAR), max(df1$YEAR)),
          step = 1
        )
      )
    ),
  fluidRow(
    chartJSRadarOutput('radarPlot' )
      )
    )
)
)
```

Comment: the `df1` object doesn't exist in the UI, you can't use `df1$YEAR` in the UI like that. If you want to build UI components based on data you need to use `renderUI()` in the server, and `uiOutput()` in the UI.

Comment: I have updated the slider in dashboardsidebar(), I am able to see my slider now. But I am encountering a new error called "Error in renderchartJSRadar({ : 
  could not find function "renderchartJSRadar"

Comment: Can you edit your question to keep it current with your issue. In your example you don't have anything in your `dashboardSidebar()`

Comment: I have added  following in dashboardSidebar(sliderInput(
     "years",
     "Select Year:",
     min = min(df1$YEAR),
      max = max(df1$YEAR),
      value = c(min(df1$YEAR), max(df1$YEAR)),
       step = 1
  )

Comment: edit the question, don't write it in a comment.